# How to decrypt the monoalphabetic substitution cipher message through substitution cipher using linux commands

Tags: encryption, frequency-analysis

I have been trying to decrypt a message which is seed labs task. I have to use linux commands. They have provided the guidelines but as I am new to this I couldn't find proper help.

What commands do I need to run in order to decrypt this message?The instructions are attached below. The ciphertext.txt file is attached as well which I need to decrypt in the plain text.

ciphertext.txt

ytn xqavhq yzhu  xu qzupvd ltmat qnncq vgxzy hmrty vbynh ytmq ixur qyhvurn
vlvhpq yhme ytn gvrrnh bnniq imsn v uxuvrnuvhmvu yxx

ytn vlvhpq hvan lvq gxxsnupnp gd ytn pncmqn xb tvhfnd lnmuqynmu vy myq xzyqny
vup ytn veevhnuy mceixqmxu xb tmq bmic axcevud vy ytn nup vup my lvq qtvenp gd
ytn ncnhrnuan xb cnyxx ymcnq ze givasrxlu eximymaq vhcavupd vaymfmqc vup
v uvymxuvi axufnhqvymxu vq ghmnb vup cvp vq v bnfnh phnvc vgxzy ltnytnh ytnhn
xzrty yx gn v ehnqmpnuy lmubhnd ytn qnvqxu pmpuy ozqy qnnc nkyhv ixur my lvq
nkyhv ixur gnavzqn ytn xqavhq lnhn cxfnp yx ytn bmhqy lnnsnup mu cvhat yx
vfxmp axubimaymur lmyt ytn aixqmur anhncxud xb ytn lmuynh xidcemaq ytvusq
ednxuratvur

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to perform a frequency analysis on your cipher text. There are many online tools available to do that, but the most powerful I found was this one:

http://www.brianveitch.com/maze-runner/frequency-analysis/index.html

Based on your cipher text, you need to make assumptions and replace each letter one by one and then analyze the final result to be sure that your answer makes sense. The more correct guesses you'll make, the more closer you will get and eventually, you'll be able to crack the final mono-alphabetic code.

Based on the cipher text you provided in your ciphertext.txt file, the following results are true (Replace the lowercase letters with uppercase letters).

`n - E
y - T
v - A
t - H
x - O
u - N
h - R
b - F
q - S
i - L
m - I
r - G
p - D
c - M
s - K
z - U
a - C
d - Y
k - X
l - W
e - P
g - B
f - V
j - Q
o - Z`

A quick way to do this is by using `tr`.

```
tr 'nyvtxuhbqimrpcszadklegfjo' 'ETAHONRFSLIGDMKUCYXWPBVQZ' < test.txt  > out.txt
```